# How to improve mouse pointer lag on Windows 10 guest in Boxes?

Tags: virtual-machine, mouse, gnome3

I am using Windows 10 as a guest in a virtual machine on Debian 10.6 "buster" in GNOME Boxes on a laptop with Ryzen 5 4500U processor, which comes with AMD® Renoir integrated graphics, but on this laptop it runs only with `llvmpipe`. I have [SPICE tools](https://www.spice-space.org/download.html) installed on the guest.

The lag of the pointer is noticeable enough to become slightly annoying. It becomes worse over the day after starting the guest. Basically, it looks as if the pointer in the guest lags slightly behind the pointer on the host machine and somewhat accelerates towards the location of the cursor on the host. There is no such behavior with Linux VMs on my computer. I see no difference in the pointer behavior when I enable or disable the option "Enhance pointer precision" in the Windows 10 guest machine. Also, the pointer sometimes "splits" into two pointers: one for the host machine and another for the guest machine, dressed accordingly.

Here is the part of the XML configuration part of the guest machine for video:

```xml
<video>
  <model type="virtio" heads="1" primary="yes">
    <acceleration accel3d="no"/>
  </model>
  <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x0"/>
</video>
```

I tried changing acceleration to "yes", but it did not help.

Comment: What virtualization software are you using? It's probably emulating a graphics tablet rather than a mouse, so any mouse pointer settings don't apply. What you're experiencing is simply a lag. Do you have appropriate integration enhancements installed on the guest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I upgraded to Debian "bullseye", which comes with GNOME Boxes 3.38.0-1. The upgrade enabled AMD® Renoir graphics on the host, but it did not remove the mouse pointer lag completely.

I installed `virt-manager` and looked for other video options to try. By trial, changing video device from `virtio` to `qxl` removed the lag completely. It seems to work more relibaly on this particular setup.

Now, the XML configuration part of the guest machine for video looks like this:

```xml
<video>
  <model type="qxl" ram="65536" vram="65536" vgamem="16384" heads="1" primary="yes">
    <acceleration accel3d="no"/>
  </model>
  <alias name="video0"/>
  <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x0"/>
</video>
```